# What is the difference between Microsoft WebMatrix and Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I understand that using the WebMatrix is easier as the tool seems more focused towards ASP.NET. However, I was curious to know through if it is possible to also create the same ASP.NET files using just Visual Studio. Would using the WebMatrix be a good start for understanding how to create web applications. Visual Basic can create applications that will run on your computer also right?

Comment: Vermeer, FrontPage, Blend, Visual Studio Web Developer ... and now Web Matrix.  Isn't marketing swell :)?  Look here: http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/

Comment: [As it seems](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebMatrix2FrontEndWebDevelopersTakeNoteASPNETPHPNodejsAndMore.aspx) WebMatrix 2 is becoming better and better. I'm not sure whether you can create libraries as well and write traditional layered apps, but intellisense and third party lib support seems superb. To some extent it exceeds VS capabilities (i.e. jQueryMobile data attributes, node.js, PHP)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webmatrix = web application focus;
Visual Studio = you decide the application focus;

If you want to do only Web and feel that Visual Studio is too much for the kind of project you want to do, which is true in a lot of cases, then I would suggest just using Web Matrix. As your project grows, however, you will soon find yourself in Visual Studio simply because it has more power and reach to build more complex systems.

I generally spin up a Web Matrix app if I want a quick catch all solution (kind of like MAMP or XAMMP) to test a small application, or play around with sql.

Comment: Is web matrix still a possibility with the release of visual studio 2013?

Comment: If it fits your needs then yes. It has support for php, and nodejs, so it is still very much in use.

Answer (score 7):

WebMatrix is a do it all package with Express IIS, Visual Studio is an IDE developed towards the .Net framework. Basically Webmatrix is specialized towards Web Development and Visual Studio is a powerhouse package that has a Web development aspect. That is the basics of it. Hopefully someone has a much more in depth answer but to tell you the truth, this is easily re-searchable via Google.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the major difference is Webmatrix supports PHP and node.js.

You can read more here :

http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/tools.aspx